# Computing the Jacobian matrix, using (at most) Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, math, matrix

I'm attempting to write a simple implementation of the Newton-Raphson method, in `Python`. I've already done so using the `SymPy` library, however what I'm working on now will (ultimately) end up running in an environment where only `Numpy` is available.

For those unfamiliar with the algorithm, it works (in my case) as follows:

---

I have some a system of symbolic equations, which I "stack" to form a matrix `F`. The unknowns are `X,Y,Z,T` (which I wish to determine). Some additional values are initially unknown, until passed to my solver, which substitutes these known values for variables in the symbolic expressions.

Now, the Jacobian matrix (`J`) of `F` is computed. This, too, is a matrix of symbolic expressions.

Now, I iterate in some range (`max_iter`). With each iteration, I form a matrix `A` by substituing for the unknowns `X,Y,Z,T` in `F` current estimates (starting with some initial values). Similarly, I form a matrix `b` by substituting for `X,Y,Z,T` current estimates.

I then obtain new estimates by solving the matrix equation `Ax = b` for `x`. This vector `x` holds `dT, dX, dY, dZ`. I then add these to current estimates for `T,X,Y,Z`, and iterate again.

---

Thus far, I've found my largest issue to be computing the Jacobian matrix. I need only to do this once, however it will be different depending upon the coefficients fed to the solver (not *unknowns*, but only known once fed to the solver, so I can't simply hard-code the Jacobian).

While I'm not terribly familiar with `Numpy`, I know that it offers `numpy.gradient`. I'm not sure, however, that this is the same as `SymPy`'s `.jacobian`.

How can the Jacobian matrix be found, either in "pure" `Python`, or with `Numpy`?

**EDIT:**

Should it be useful to you, more information on the problem can be found [here]. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3934035/822508). It can be formulated a few different ways, however (as of now) I'm writing it as 4 equations of the form:

`\sqrt{(X-x_i)^2+(Y-y_i)^2+(Z-z_i)^2 }= c * (t_i-T)`

Where `X,Y,Z` and `T` are unknown.

This describes the solution to a localization problem, where we know (a) the location of n >= 4 observers in a 3-dimensional space, (b) the time at which each observer "saw" some signal, and (c) the velocity of the signal. The goal is to determine the coordinates of the signal source `X,Y,Z` (and, as a side effect, the time of emission, `T`).

Notice that I've tried (*many*) other approaches to solving this problem, and all leads point toward a combination of Newton-Raphson with regression.

Comment: I think you want to optimize the cost matrix using partial differentiation. Is that so ?

Comment: @MSS I'm not too awfully familiar with the terminology of the topic but, yes, I believe you could characterize this as such. I'm attempting to solve a (particularly troublesome) system which, as it turns out, is most reliably solved by first obtaining an approximation via least-squares regression, and then feeding that approximation as initial values to Newton-Raphson.

Comment: `numpy.gradient` is not what you want. If you can calculate the Jacobian analytically, you only have to code a matrix valued function. If not, you need to make the numerical   derivatives of the according vector valued function.

Comment: @mikuszefski Yes, as I recall the gradient is a "special case" of the jacobian (or perhaps its the other way around...)

Comment: Yes, the point is that `numpy.gradient` is doing something "completely" different. It calculates the numerical gradient of a function `f` that is given as list.....you may misuse it for the Jabobian, but there are probaby better ways

Comment: If not given as function, you'll need finite-differences method.

Comment: @KeithMadison this is an interesting problem. You can help others help you by saying exactly what is the function that you are working with. The best way to approach the problem almost certainly hinges on details, so you'll get to a working solution sooner by saying exactly what is the function.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks for the suggestion. Updated with additional information.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the final term is `c` times `t_i - T`? where `c` is signal propagation speed? It might help to write it as `c*(t_i - T)` in that case. Also, the first thing I'll suggest is squaring both sides to get rid of the sqrt.

Comment: @RobertDodier Yes, that's correct (apologies for the bad formatting).

Comment: Well, for a given value of T, maybe the problem is simpler. How about formulating the problem as: minimize residual (left-hand side minus right-hand side) as a function of T, and then use some heuristics and/or minimization algorithm for that one-dimensional search. Within that, apply some known or unknown method for finding X, Y, Z for a given value of T.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks again for the suggestion-- good point. Perhaps you could suggest an algorithm that would be reliable for this purpose ("finding" T)?

Comment: Maybe just step along at fixed intervals (could be relatively large) until you get in the neighborhood, and then apply golden section search or something like that.